# How to extend admin config menu with custom panel Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal-8

I am trying to add programmaticaly a custom,`parent` panel to the `admin/config` menu, so i can add other links to it, config pages of other modules etc. How can that be done? I am able to add custom module, under `admin/config/development/my_module`, for example, but i would like to group all my modules under same, `custom parent panel`.

Comment: To be more precise, i would like to create a panel title, simiral to default PEOPLE, SYSTEM, CONTENT AUTHORING, etc ... making it available to be the parent of my different, existing, standalone custome modules

Answer (score 0):

Check in contrib modules for examples. Example from message module - message.links.menu.yml

```
message.overview_templates:
  title: 'Message templates'
  parent: system.admin_structure
  description: 'Manage message templates.'
  route_name: message.overview_templates

message.main_settings:
  title: 'Message'
  route_name: message.main_settings
  parent: system.admin_config
  description: 'Tools that enhance the user interface.'
  weight: -10

message.settings:
  title: 'Message'
  description: 'Message settings.'
  parent: 'message.main_settings'
  route_name: message.settings
```

Also, check the official documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-menu-link

Comment: Thank you for your time Denis. Regarding the `route_name: message.overview_templates` , do i have to define a route with the help of a form or a controller class, under the route name of `overview_templates`?I am affraid this will output an error, like no such route is defined